Simplicial self-maps of arbitrary degree
For context, here is the problem (from this set of problems by Oscar Randal-Williams):

I've done parts (i) through (iii), but I'm having trouble with part (iv). My idea is to use induction, so that if we have a simplicial map $f: K \to K$ for a triangulation $K$ of $S^{n-1}$ of degree $d$ for $n \geq 2$, then we obtain a simplicial map $Sf: SK \to SK$, where $SK$ is a triangulation of $S^n$, also of degree $d$ (since they agree under some isomorphism on the homology groups). These simplicial maps then induce the required maps $S^n \to S^n$.
We need therefore a base case simplicial map $f: K \to K$ for a triangulation $K$ of $S^1$ to get started. I know that $z \mapsto z^d$ gives the required continuous map, however I'm having trouble translating this into a simplicial self-map $K \to K$ for some triangulation $K$ of $S^1$. In particular, it seems that to get a simplicial approximation of $z \mapsto z^d$ for $d > 1$, we need two distinct triangulations of $S^1$, with the domain being strictly "finer" and codomain strictly "coarser".
Question: Is it possible to have a simplicial self-map (i.e. same simplicial structure for the domain and codomain) for a triangulation of $S^1$ of arbitrary degree $d$? If not, how can we deduce (iv) from the previous parts?

You should always properly cite someone else's work: where is this problem from?

@JohnPalmieri Sorry, let me make an edit.

The way to deduce (iv) from the others is to modify (iii) so that the domain and codomain may be distinct triangulations of $S^n$.
To prove that you can't do this with the same triangulation, suppose that $K$ is a polygon with $m$ vertices with $m \geq 3$; then $K$ is a triangulation of $S^1$. If $f: K \to K$ is a simplicial map which is not onto, then it induces zero on homology. Therefore if $f_* \neq 0$, then $f$ must induce a surjection on both vertices and edges, and since the domain and codomain have the same vertex count and edge count, $f$ must induce a bijection on vertices and edges. The only possible degrees for such a map are $\pm 1$ — you cannot get a map of arbitrary degree this way.
(In degree 1 there are no boundaries, so two cycles are homologous if and only if they are equal. The cycle generating $d$ times a homology generator must label each edge with coefficient $\pm d$, and so map sending edges bijectively to edges can't send the appropriately oriented sum of all of the edges to $\pm d$ times itself unless $d = \pm 1$.)
